# Boxplots in a single graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

In ggplot, how to create boxplots in a single graph by group.If i have a data

```
data(iris)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris) + geom_boxplot(Sepal.Length)
```

In this way, I know to create the boxplots for other columns. How to group and plot simultaneously in a singleplot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this. You have to reshape your data to long and using a variable as reference. In the case of this example `Species`. Then use common `aesthetics` elements for axis and `fill` options and the plot will be done. Here the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
#Code
iris %>% pivot_longer(-Species) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=Species,y=value,fill=name))+
    geom_boxplot()
```

Output:

[image]